# Can't find Compose Desktop Preview tab in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, compose-desktop

I can't find `preview` tab in my editor for `Compose Desktop`!
[image]

how can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!
you have to install `Compose Multiplatform` plugin

Answer (score 1):

Go To Plugins in **Settings**,
then search for *Compose Multiplatform* in the **Marketplace**
Click Install
And Should restart IDE for that plugin to take effect, should see a Multiplatform icon next to your preview

Enjoy.